# Excluding link at the end while pulling tweets in tweepy Streaming

Tags: python, api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I am pulling `text` or `extended_text` using tweepy streaming, but when I pull these tweets, there is always a t.co/randomletters link at the end that leads to nowhere. What is it and how do I get rid of it?
Here is an example:

```
 "text": "To make room for more expression, we will now count all emojis as equal—including those with gender‍‍‍ ‍‍and skin tone modifiers https://t.co(forward slash)MkGjXf9aXm"
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my experience with twitter and tweepy goes, these URL's are included in a tweet's text whenever there is a URL of some sort in the actual tweet, so we can't really avoid getting them.

You could remove them after you get them, this is a simple regex that replaces the pattern of these URL's with a blank string.

```
import re

re.sub(r' https://t.co/\w{10}', '', tweet_text)
```

Comment: Oh, right - does it also include the url when there is a video or photo in the tweet?

Comment: Yes, if there's anything other than pure text really, you'll get a URL of this form in the API response.